# Why checkbox checked does not work for element in different element / div?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to have hamburger menu in header and menu to toggle from side inside content, under header, but I have problem with it.
I think that for some reason selector `input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarMenu` does not want to work if checkboox is in different div than `#sidebarMenu` itself.

```
#sidebarMenu, .sidebarMenu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    transform: translateX(-270px);
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%), 0 0px 10px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarMenu {
    transform: translateX(0) !important;
}
```

This does not work:

```
<div class="container">     
<input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
<label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
<div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
<div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
<div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
</label>
</div>

<div id="content" class="site-content container clear">   
<div id="sidebarMenu">
<ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

This works:

```
<div class="container">     
<input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
<label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
<div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
<div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
<div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
</label>
<div id="sidebarMenu">
<ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, the `~` selects a #sidebarMenu that is *a sibling* of input[type="checkbox"]:checked

It doesn't work when you put the  wrapper around it because the input will *cease* to be a sibling of #sidebarMenu.

EDIT: It looks like you'll need a JS solution if you really want to use the markup from the first code snippet.

You'll want to set an Event listener for the checkbox and toggle the class for the sidebar menu. Technically, you don't need an input either but it may look something like this:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('sidebarMenu').classList.toggle('menu-open')
})
```

Comment: I understand.
How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the HTML in the first example (the one that doesn't work) a requirement?

Comment: It would be easier for me to continue developing theme for BuddyPress, bbPress etc. if I can accomplish it by first example.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to use Javascript because you can't traverse up the DOM with CSS Selectors. I will update my reply with a JS solution